# How to deal with unknown classes with a convolution neural network classifier?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm quite new into the DL and ML field.
I'm training a CNN able to classify 3 different classes, however I would like in the testing phase to make the CNN able to not misclassify images that do not belong to any of the three classes.
I understand that the network will always provide one of the three class for any input testing image, but I was expecting quite low score values when the image is "unknown", in order to apply some threshold.
Is there a way to improve the CNN in order to obtain this result? Or it is better to change the classifier?
I was also thinking to add a fourth class, the "unknown" one, but for the purpose of my study it would be difficult to obtain a training set of unknown images.

Comment: The term of art for the task of not having training examples for all classes is "open set learning." Here's a recent review article. C. Geng, S. -J. Huang and S. Chen, "Recent Advances in Open Set Recognition: A Survey," in IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, vol. 43, no. 10, pp. 3614-3631, 1 Oct. 2021, doi: 10.1109/TPAMI.2020.2981604.

Comment: Maybe *semi-supervised learning* is another useful search term